# Why subscribe results are not in order - Angular 4

Tags: angular, sorting, service, subscribe

It is possible to receive subscribe results in order ?

Let me explain with code:

```
//Array with date values in order(last 30 Days)

  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        date = this.substractDays(date, 1);
        arrayDate.push(date);
    }

    console.log(arrayDate);

    arrayDate.forEach((item, index) => {
        month = item.getMonth();
        month++;

        newFormatDate = item.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + item.getDate();
//get date for each days
        this.subscription = this.dataService.APICall(newFormatDate).subscribe(data => {
            this.Results.push({ "date": item, "data": data.count });

 });
console.log(Results);
```

**First Console**

[image: First console.log]

**Second Console**

[image: Second console.log]

Thanks everyone

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you're asking... Are you asking how to sort the array by date?

Comment: Yes, create an observable from your date array and use swtichMap for your api call

Answer (score 1):

`Observables` are asynchronous, so you may expect them to return in random order unless you use some good Observable operators like [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html).

Instead of using `forEach`, You could do something like

```
from(arrayDate).pipe(
     concatMap((item) => {
      let newFormatDate = item.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + item.getDate();
      this.dataService.APICall(newFormatDate )
         .subscribe((data) => {
            this.Results.push({ "date": item, "data": data.count })
      })
}));
```